# Can I get an exception object's type name in the catch(...) block?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can I get an exception object's type name in the catch(...) block?

```
#define EXIT_THROUGH_EXCEPTION 1
#define EXIT_THROUGH_UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION 2

void error_info(ostream& stream, const string& msg, unsigned int line);

int main()
try{ 
  // Here is main code...
}
catch (exception& ex){ // Any exception based on the std::exception class
  error_info(cerr, ex.what(), __LINE__);
  return EXIT_THROUGH_EXCEPTION;
}
catch (...){ // other exception type  
  // TODO: what is instead of "???"?
  error_info(cerr, "Unknown exception: " + typeid("???").name,  __LINE__);
  return EXIT_THROUGH_UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, standard doesn't specify rich support for this, sadly!

Comment: I used [this UntypedException](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/exception.html) approach in [UnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and with [VectoredExceptionHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Visual C++ x86 builds. VectoredHandler is called before C++ exception handlers allowing to save exception pointers to thread local variable and analyze in c++ handler. Of course this is very implementation specific but may help a lot with crash dump analysis.